# Angular2/Nativescript: When adding a new item to a Listview the previous item gets overridden

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to display a list of items in a ListView.  I added a GridLayout to the template of the ListView and then I add the item name, quantity and a remove (font-awesome trash icon) to the three columns of the GridLayout.  It seems to work fine but whenever I add a new item to the list in the view the previous item gets overridden by the most recent.  i.e. The list contains only one row which contains the most recent item instead of adding the most recent item below the current in a new GridLayout.  Any idea what might be going wrong here?  My code is below

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">
        <ListView [items]="stockTakeDetailList">
            <template let-captureItem="item" let-i="index">
                <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *">
                    <Label row="0" col="0" class="list-group-item" textWrap="true" [text]="captureItem.ProductDetail_Name"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="1" class="list-group-item" [text]="captureItem.Qty"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="2" class="list-group-item font-awesome" text="&#xf1f8;" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(i)"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
            </template>
        </ListView>         
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

my component code for adding an item:
submitCaptureItem(captureItem: CaptureItemModel) {      
    this.busy = true;  
    this.restService.postCaptureItem(captureItem)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        this.busy = false;
        if (res.ResponseCode !== 0) {
            this.showError(res.CustomError);
        } else {
            this.stockTakeDetailList.unshift(res.StockTakeDetail);      
            this.product = null;        
        }
    },
    (res) => {      
    this.busy = false;
    this.showError("technical error");
        console.log(res);
    }); 
    this.barcode = '';
    this.qty = '';  
  }
```

Comment: whats your code for adding more data? can you post it?

Comment: you also dont need a scrollview around a listview

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  I just added my code for adding an item.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: are you sure `res.stocktakedetail` is there? and did you remove the scrollview?

Comment: Yes i'm sure the component code is working as everything worked fine before.  I displayed the info in a StackLayout before and wanted to try using a GridLayout recently...

Comment: Will try it now without the scrollview

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  Thanks a lot removing the ScrollView fixed it:)  Please add that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to have a scrollview around a listview, the listview itself has a scrollview built in. Use this:

```
<StackLayout *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">
    <ListView [items]="stockTakeDetailList">
        <template let-captureItem="item" let-i="index">
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *">
                <Label row="0" col="0" class="list-group-item" textWrap="true" [text]="captureItem.ProductDetail_Name"></Label>
                <Label row="0" col="1" class="list-group-item" [text]="captureItem.Qty"></Label>
                <Label row="0" col="2" class="list-group-item font-awesome" text="&#xf1f8;" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(i)"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>         
</StackLayout>
```